# Forms authentication with URL rewriting

Tags: iis, authentication, rewrite, iis-8.5

I've got forms authentication set on the top level of my site via the web.config, and I also have a URL rewrite rule to go from mysite.com/plex/ via a reverse proxy to another localhost server; however, this bypasses my authentication. How can I make the forms authentication redirect to the login page before performing the URL rewrite to the proxy?

Thanks.

Comment: What have your Internet search yielded? I see a lot of articles in various KnowledgeBase forums on this topic.

Comment: I've seen a lot about how to do one or the other, but none on both combined

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following in the section system.webServer. 

<system.webServer>
   ...
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
   ...
</system.webServer>




In IIS Manager root of website: 
* enable Anonymous Authentication
* enable Forms Authentication
* .NET Authorization Rules: Deny Anonymous Users; Allow All Users
* Authorization Rules: Allow All Users
* Application Pool: Managed Pipeline Mode = Integrated
This should fix the issue.
```